# Select distinct values across columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I'm trying to create a query that returns the distinct values across 4 columns in a single row. My where clause will limit the depth of the results to just one row but keep the data separated into columns. For example

`SELECT color1, color2, color3, color4 FROM art WHERE id = 1`

would return (in columns)

`|Red |Blue |Blue |Green |`

But I want only the distinct values

`|Red |Blue |Green |     |`

Is there such a thing as using an unpivot and then pivot back to columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to `UNPIVOT` your data and then `PIVOT` via a `dense_rank()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[Color1] varchar(50),[Color2] varchar(50),[Color3] varchar(50),[Color4] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
  (1,'Red','Blue','Blue','Green')

Select *
 From  (
        Select A.ID
              ,B.Item
              ,Col = concat('Color',dense_rank() over (partition by ID order by Item) )
         from @YourTable A
         Cross Apply ( values (color1)
                             ,(color2)
                             ,(color3)
                             ,(color4)
                     ) B(Item)
         Where ID=1
       ) src
 Pivot (max(item) for Col in (Color1,Color2,Color3,Color4) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Color1  Color2  Color3  Color4
1   Blue    Green   Red     NULL
```

**Note:**  The `Where ID=1` is optional